# jquery builder with bootstrap 4.5 not working

Tags: bootstrap-4, jquery-query-builder

Here is jsfiddle attempting to use jquery querybuilder with bootstrap 4.5

Referencing

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.min.js

HTML

```
<div id="builder"></div>
```

JS to get it going

```
$('#builder').queryBuilder({
    filters: [{id:1}] 
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CapedInOveralls/mhvae412/2)

Any ideas why I get

> Uncaught TypeError: $.extendext is not a function

According to the docs the extendext js is included the dist and the only extras required should be jquery and bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Oops! I needed to the the "standalone" js not the one in the post.

The correct url is

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js

Here for anyone else goofing :-)